# Why getFieldValue from antd return undefined for the input value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm have 3 files (form.validation.ts , create-collocation-order-rf-antennas-form.tsx , create-order-product-info.new.tsx)
create-order-product-info.new.tsx => the parents component that hold the create-order-product-info.new.tsx component
form.validation.ts => that file hold some rules I'm using it for validate the form , at this file there's a rule called getFieldRule , with this rule i can get the value for any input and i named it quantity then I will doing some stuff and i need the quantity value for (if) statement
the problem is the if statement always return the Promise.reject and never return the Promise.resolve because the quantity is (undefined) , I want to logged the quantity  value to the console to be able to execute the Promise.resolve at the if statement

```
export const getFieldRule =
  (t: TType, fieldName: string, form: FormInstance) =>
  () => ({
    async validator(_: RuleObject, value?: string) {
      const quantity = form.getFieldValue(fieldName);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(' ~ file: form.validation.ts:75 ~ validator ~ quantity:', quantity);
      const values = value?.split('-');
      if (!quantity || !values || values.length !== quantity) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(t('form.validate.numbersByDashes')));
      }
      const isValid = values.every((val) => !isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)));
      if (isValid) {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid height values.'));
    },
  });
```

```
export const QUOTE_RF_ANTENNAS_FORM_ITEMS = (
  t: TType,
  form: FormInstance
): QuoteProductInfoRfFormItems => ({
  quantity: {
    name: QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_RF_FORM_ITEMS.quantity,
    rules: [doubleNumberPatternRule(t)],
  },
  height: {
    name: QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_RF_FORM_ITEMS.height,
    dependencies: [QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_MV_FORM_ITEMS.quantity],
    rules: [
      separatedNumbersWithDashes(t),
      getFieldRule(t, QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_MV_FORM_ITEMS.quantity, form),
    ],
  },
  azimuth: {
    name: QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_RF_FORM_ITEMS.azimuth,
    dependencies: [QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_MV_FORM_ITEMS.quantity],
    rules: [
      separatedNumbersWithDashes(t),
      getFieldRule(t, QUOTE_PRODUCT_INFO_MV_FORM_ITEMS.quantity, form),
    ],
  },
});

export const CreateCollocationOrderRfAntennasFormComponent: FC<Props> = ({ t }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const getItems = useGetCollocationProductInfoChildrenProductsFormItems({
    items: QUOTE_RF_ANTENNAS_FORM_ITEMS(t, form),
  });

  return (
    <CreateCollocationOrderFormCard
      formListName={QuoteProductInfoChildrenProduct.rfAntennas}
      getItems={getItems}
      maxFormCards={MAX_NUMBER_OF_RF_ANTENNAS}
      t={t}
      title={t('createCollocation.rfAntennas.title')}
    />
  );
};

export const CreateCollocationOrderRfAntennasForm = memo(
  withTranslate(CreateCollocationOrderRfAntennasFormComponent)
);
```

```
export const CreateOrderProductInfoComponent: FC<Props> = ({
  companyId,
  onFinish,
  setForm,
  onChangeSite,
  quoteItemProductType: defaultQuoteItemProductType,
  siteData,
  quoteItem,
}) => {
  const { data: { getDescription, getTitle } = {} } = useOrdersProducts(companyId);
  const lovInfo = useQuoteLov();
  const agreementsLovInfo = useAgreementsLov(companyId);
  const [formRef] = Form.useForm();
  const [formAutoValidated, setFormAutoValidated] = useState(false);

  const initialValues = useInitialValues({ siteData, quoteItem });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setForm(formRef);
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  const quoteItemProductType = quoteItem?.quoteItemProductType || defaultQuoteItemProductType;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!formAutoValidated && quoteItem?.id && lovInfo.isSuccess && agreementsLovInfo.isSuccess) {
      formRef.validateFields();
      setFormAutoValidated(true);
    }
  }, [agreementsLovInfo.isSuccess, formAutoValidated, formRef, lovInfo.isSuccess, quoteItem?.id]);

  if (!initialValues || lovInfo.isLoading || agreementsLovInfo.isLoading) {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Spin />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Form
        onFinish={onFinish}
        form={formRef}
        id={'CREATE_COLLOCATION_PRODUCT_INFO_FORM'}
        name={'CREATE_COLLOCATION_PRODUCT_INFO_FORM'}
        layout="vertical"
        scrollToFirstError
        initialValues={initialValues}
        requiredMark={false}
      >
        <StyledVerticalSpace>
          <CreateOrderCommonForm
            initialValues={initialValues}
            agreementLovData={agreementsLovInfo?.data}
            productTitle={getTitle?.(quoteItemProductType)}
            productDescription={getDescription?.(quoteItemProductType)}
            quoteType={quoteItemProductType}
          />
          <CreateOrderSiteInfo
            onChangeSite={onChangeSite}
            quoteLov={lovInfo.data}
            type={quoteItemProductType}
          />
          <CreateCollocationOrderRfAntennasForm form={formRef} />
          <CreateCollocationOrderMwAntennasForm form={formRef} />
          <CreateCollocationOrderRruRfModulesForm />
          <CreateCollocationOrderOtherActiveEquipment />
          <CreateCollocationOrderPower quoteLoV={lovInfo.data} />
          <CreateCollocationOrderOtherDetails quoteItemProductType={quoteItemProductType} />
        </StyledVerticalSpace>
      </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export const CreateOrderProductInfoNew = memo(withTranslate(CreateOrderProductInfoComponent));
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).